# How to disable frontend for CMS/API-only, headless Magento 2.3

Tags: theme, frontend, magento2.3, pwa

I'm currently working on a web-app that uses Magento 2.3 as a CMS-only. How can I disable the customer-facing frontend and leave only the admin pages accessible?

Alternatively, is there a way to set Magento theme so it returns a static html file (something like 404.html) when non-admin/rest routes are visited?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something with your Apache/nginx configuration.

Try using httpAuth to block Magento from the public. Or you could use an IP whitelist to only allow certain IPs to be able to view it.